# How IIS handles request for both MVC and Asp.net at high level

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, request

I am trying to understand the .net pipeline and how request is processed (both MVC and Asp.net )and I have come to this understanding.
Can someone please comment if I am missing any step and my doubts.

**My Understanding:**

1)Request comes to IIS.

2)IIS is just a process and points the request to application pool it is mapped.

3)Application pool have worker process .

4)Worker process loads ISAPI filter and create runtime objects.

5)Application_start is called from  global.asax of application is called.

6)For MVC,routing is checked and then request is moved to particular controller.Similarly asp.net request are "somehow" moved to particular page.

**Question**-A application pool have many application and hence many application_start method.How does it is mapped to correct application?

**Question**-Asp.net request are **"somehow"** moved to particular page.Can someone tells me at high level how this happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Question-Asp.net request are "somehow" moved to particular page.Can
>   someone tells me at high level how this happens.

Request goes through defined stages in pipeline (irrespective of ASP.NET webforms or ASP.NET MVC)

When the stage ExecuteRequestHandler comes - appropriate handler is processed. For example : in case of webforms your page basically inherit `System.Web.UI.Page` which implements `IHttpHandler` interface whereas in case of MVC; `MVCHandler` implementing `IHttpHandler` is invoked.

IHttpHandler ProcessRequest() method in case of MVC takes care of executing desired controller where as in case of webforms page_load method is called.

Now what handler to be used is decided at MapRequestHandler stage in application pipeline.

[image]

You can get detailed flow info here : [MVC Request Pipleline](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1028156/A-Detailed-Walkthrough-of-ASP-NET-MVC-Request-Life)

> Question-A application pool have many application and hence many
>   application_start method.How does it is mapped to correct application?

Quoting from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee797229(v=cs.20).aspx) directly :

> A request arrives and the ASP.NET runtime creates an AppDomain for the
>   application. It then creates the first instance of the HttpApplication
>   class within the AppDomain. The AppDomain might create subsequent
>   instances of the HttpApplication class, because ASP.NET can create a
>   pool of instances. Each request to the Web server is serviced by a
>   single instance of the HttpApplication class.

Comment: Thanks but again I have a doubt.Yousaid,each application has an application instance but how does correct application instnace is called from application pool.Does it make any sense?An application pool can have multiple application instance

Comment: @poojaMalik : Thanks. I realized mistake in my response and corrected it. hope now it makes sesne..

Comment: @poojaMalik : also each application in app pool is isolated via application domain